# iOS: Screen no longer receives Touches after calling dismissModalViewController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have two views. Very simple set up just to play around with the camera roll.

One view will bring up the camera roll using:

```
[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
```

which is triggered by a `UIButton`. It brings up the camera, everything's fine.

After taking a picture, I am calling the following to dismiss the controller:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Again, everything is working.

But the view that brings up the `imagePicker` Controller no longer receives touch (the `UIButton` will no longer brings up the camera again) after the Modal View is dismissed.

It will only start to receive touches again when I switch to another view and come back.

I have been searching for a solution to this problem but have not been successful in finding anything. Thanks in advance.

EDIT (Adding code):

**In CameraController.m**

**This is where brings up the Camera Roll**

(Subclass of `UIViewController` conforming to 
`<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>`)

```
//UIButton that brings up the imagePicker
- (IBAction)useCamera
{
        [self prepareImagePicker];
        [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
}

//Initializing ImagePicker
- (void)prepareImagePicker
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self;

    OverlayCameraView *cameraOverlay = [[OverlayCameraView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){{0, 0}, 320, 480} andTheCameraController:self];
        self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlay;
   }
}

//Delegate Method when a picture is taken
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    self.imagePicker.delegate = nil;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    self.imagePicker = nil;
    self.imageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];  
}
```

**In OverlayCameraView.m**

```
//Camera Overlay Class (Subclass of UIView)

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andTheCameraController:(CameraController*)cameraController
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        self.camera = cameraController;
    //.…2 UIButtons set up

    }
    return self;
}

//Overlay Cancel Button
- (void) cancel
{  
   [self.camera dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}

//Overlay Take Picture Button
- (void) takeAPicture
{
    [self.camera.imagePicker takePicture];
}
```

Comment: Log information about the button to the console after the modal is dismissed. Is the button's frame displaced? Does the button's frame match the button's constraints?

Comment: @bilobatum I just checked. the Button's frame is the same both before and after. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated` on the picker not `self` via the  `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` methods.

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

or if you are keeping a reference to it:

```
[self.imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

EDIT:

Based on the revised code, I believe

```
self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlay;
```

should be:

```
self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlay.view;
```

Also this will cause a +2 reference count and will leak if you are not using ARC:

```
self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

It should be for proper reference counting:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePicker = picker;
[picker release];
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both the above, but none worked. I tried to do a `NSLog` in `touchesBegan`. The view did receive touch before but after the controller is dismissed, the method was no longer called.

Comment: Then you need to post more code cause you are doing something else to disable the view.

Comment: Made some edits based on new code. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I will go ahead and try it. BTW, I am using ARC.